# has_many with two has_one's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many

I have a User model that has_many parents.
I want that user model to have one father and one mother.

So my class Parent belongs_to user

Currently I have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parents

  has_one :father, :class_name => 'Parent', :foreign_key => 'user_id', :conditions => {:type => 'male'}
  has_one :mother, :class_name => 'Parent', :foreign_key => 'user_id', :conditions => {:type => 'female'}
end

class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The problem is in my controller.

```
...
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.mother = Parent.new(:type => 'female')
  @user.father = Parent.new(:type => 'male')
...
```

When I go into the edit, it creates and throws the 2 parents into the database without even having changed anything in the form. For example, when I click edit on a user, I go to the edit page. When I look into the database, they're already created.

My form looks like so:

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  = f.fields_for :father do |father_form|
    etc...
  = f.fields_for :mother do |mother_form|
    etc...
```

I've tried doing something alone the lines of this in my controller:

```
...
@user.parents.build(:type => 'male')
@user.parents.build(:type => 'female')
...
```

But the form doesn't show up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do users have many Parents but then they are restricted to a single mother and father? What other kinds of parents do you expect them to have? Maybe you could just not even have the has_many :parents which would start to simplify things.

Comment: It's just to portray the model I'm trying to reach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use

```
@user.build_father(:type => 'male')
@user.build_mother(:type => 'female')
```

instead of

```
@user.mother = Parent.new(:type => 'female')
@user.father = Parent.new(:type => 'male')
```

in your action

Comment: This worked. Is there any way to prevent them from going into the database unless there are values inputted on the data elements for the parents?

Comment: Yes, you can do it by specifying option :reject_if in `accepts_nested_attributes_for :father` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :mother`. Check manual here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for